# Python - Creating a function which checks for new elements in lists of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm quite confused with how to create a function which inspects sublists in a list and checks whether these sublists have a unique element in the whole list itself.

```
alphabet_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f',], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

alphabet_2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

These are just examples.

For alphabet_1, since the second sublist has at least one new element in the whole list, it goes to the next sublist and then the next which fails since the fourth sublist has no new elements in the whole list, it stops. Then it counts how many sublists it has past through aka 4 (up till the stop)

For alphabet_2, since the second sublist has 0 new to the whole list, it stops. This passes through 2 (up till the stop).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An expected output for lets say alphabet_1 is 4 and alphabet_2 is 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_alphabet(a):
    i = 0
    curr_a = []
    for l in a:
        upd_a = list(set(curr_a + l))
        if len(upd_a) == len(curr_a):
            break
        i += 1
        curr_a = upd_a
    return i, curr_a
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,  would you know how to format the code so that it requires two fails in order for the function to stop counting. For instance, a second sublist and third sublist do not have any new elements, then the function stops and counts 4 .

Comment: instead of break add a counter and then check the counter; initialise to 0 before the loop and instead of break add one to this, after the first if then check if this counter has reached a threshold and break there

Answer (score 0):

Not a specialist by all means, also not familiar with python.

just a thought: save every element which has already occurred in the "super list" in another list.

All you do is check every element against the new list with the already occurred items. Once one sublist's count for "new Items (Items that have not yet occurred in the superlist" = 0 you stop checking and instead count the amount of sublists you went through.

process:

1. create occuredItems list (String)
2. create checkedLists variable (Integer)
3. create uniqueItems (Integer) for every List you check
4. check every element in your super list and add the item to the occuredItems and set uniqueItems+1 if it hast not yet been part of the list
5. if you checked the last item of every sublist you have to check for uniqueItems (of this list) to be > 0. in order to continue with the next sublist. If uniqueItems (for this list) is indeed > 0 : set checkedLists+1
   if uniqueItems = 0 your algorithm should stop and continue with point 6
6. you can just return checkedLists in order to get the amount of sublists checked, before one sublist has no unique Items.

I hope this made any sense to you. Just saw this post and thought I could maybe help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try your process out!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
from itertools import accumulate
from itertools import takewhile

alphabet_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f',], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
alphabet_2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]



def evaluate(l1, l2):
    s = set(l2)
    if s.issubset(l1):
        return False

    return s | set(l1)

def check(alphabet_):
    l = len(list(takewhile(bool, accumulate(alphabet_ , evaluate)))) + 1 
    return  min(l, len(alphabet_))

print(check(alphabet_1))
print(check(alphabet_2))
```

output:

```
4
2
```

the elements are passed throw `itertools.acumulate` where the `evaluate` function it is checking if each sublist has new elements or not, when a sublist it is found to not have any new elements it returns `False`, at this moment `itertools.takewile` will stop the iteration and then the final lenght it is returned

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm quite new to these tools so I'll play around with them!

Comment: If there is a condition where it takes two failed sublists with no new elements to stop the iteration, where would you alter the code?

Comment: you will have to use enumerate over your alphabet, but I will say this is a case for another question